# Why doesn't awscli sync work in my windows service?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, service, synchronization

I want to write some code that synchronizes a local directory to a s3 bucket as a windows service every 10 seconds. To do this, I am using the aws cli sync, and am using `os.system` to access the aws CLI.

Here is a simple example of my code:

```
x = 'aws s3 sync C:\path\to\folder s3://bucket-to-sync/'

def syncDirectory(*args)
   os.system(*args)

syncDirectory(x)
```

Now this code works fine in a regular python script and syncs as expected. However, when I create and run it as a windows service, it doesn't sync.

I've used the code from [this](https://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/) page to create and run the service, and just replaced the main function with the code listed above.

```
class PythonCornerExample(SMWinservice):
    _svc_name_ = "ServiceTest"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Service Example"
    _svc_description_ = "Syncing dir to s3 bucket"

    def start(self):
        self.isrunning = True

    def stop(self):
        self.isrunning = False

    def main(self):
        while self.isrunning:
            os.system('aws s3 sync C:\path\to\folder s3://bucket-to-sync/')
            time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PythonCornerExample.parse_command_line()
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, and I've tried to debug this code from the command prompt but it says it's working fine but nothing shows up in my bucket. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is Service running as 'you', or as another Windows user? If it is another user, it probably doesn't have access to a credentials file. Can you try redirecting output to a file? eg: `aws s3 sync source destination >C:\TEMP\output.txt`

Comment: I dont understand why you are using cli to do this. Why didn't you consider using aws sdk for python ? its clean.

Comment: Wow, thank you - that seemed to have been the issue. When I switched accounts to my local login, the service was able to sync my file! Is it possible to grant the local system account access to the awscli?

Comment: @ArunK As far as I knew, the aws cli sync tool handled all the use cases that I need. I couldn't find any advantages to using boto3 over the cli, and if you know some I would love to know.